# Help finding parameterization for a surface integral

Tags: multivariable-calculus, area, surface-integrals

> Find the surface area above the xy plane which is defined by: $x^2+y^2+z^2=1, x^2+y^2 \leq x$

I am first trying to find a parameterization which should be simple enough to work with.

I though about using spherical coordinates:
$$ x=\sin(\theta)\cos(\phi)$$
$$ y=\sin(\theta)\sin(\phi) $$
$$z=\sqrt{1+\sin^2(\theta)}$$

Which should work but the problem here is that I'm not sure how to express where $\phi$ is defined.

Because we have $0 \leq \theta \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$, and $\sin^2(\theta) \leq \sin(\theta) \cos(\phi) \Rightarrow  \sin(\theta) \leq \cos(\phi) $.

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Note that$$x^2+y^2\leqslant x\iff\left(x-\frac12\right)^2+y^2\leqslant\frac14.$$So, you're after the area of the surface $z=\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}$ with $x$ and $y$ such that $\left(x-\frac12\right)^2+y^2\leqslant\frac14$. This area is equal to\begin{multline}\int_0^1\int_{-\sqrt{x-x^2}}^{\sqrt{x-x^2}}\sqrt{\frac{x^2}{1-x^2-y^2}+\frac{y^2}{1-x^2-y^2}+1}\,\mathrm dy\,\mathrm dx=\\=\int_0^1\int_{-\sqrt{x-x^2}}^{\sqrt{x-x^2}}\frac1{\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}}\,\mathrm dy\,\mathrm dx.\end{multline}In polar coordinates, this is\begin{align}\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\int_0^{\cos(\theta)}\frac\rho{\sqrt{1-\rho^2}}\,\mathrm d\rho\,\mathrm d\theta&=\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\left[-\sqrt{1-\rho^2}\right]_{\rho=0}^{\rho=\cos(\theta)}\,\mathrm d\theta\\&=\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}1-\bigl|\sin(\theta)\bigr|\,\mathrm d\theta\\&=2\int_0^{\pi/2}1-\sin(\theta)\,\mathrm d\theta\\&=\pi-2.\end{align}

Comment: You’re a real teacher for this kinds of problems. Love your ways . 

Answer (score 1):

Unit sphere: $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$, Cylinder: $x^2+y^2 \leq x, z \geq 0$. Please note the equality in equation of the sphere and inequality in the equation of the cylinder which means we need to find the surface area of the sphere that is bound by the cylinder for $z \geq 0$.

As you mentioned in spherical coordinates, $x = \rho \cos\theta \sin\phi, y = \rho \sin\theta \sin\phi, z = \rho \cos\phi$.

For sphere, the surface is $\rho = 1$

Equation of the cylinder $x^2+y^2 \leq x$ in spherical coordinates becomes
$\rho = \cos \theta \csc \phi$

At the intersection of the cylinder and the sphere,

$\rho = \cos\theta \csc \phi = 1 \implies \phi = \arcsin(\cos\theta)$

Also note the cylinder has radius of $\frac{1}{2}$ and its center is at $(\frac{1}{2}, 0, z)$. For the cylinder in $XY$ plane, $\theta$ varies from $-\frac{\pi}{2} \leq \theta \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$.

For the given sphere, $|r'_{\theta} \times r'_{\phi}| = \sin\phi$

So the integral for the surface area is

$\displaystyle \int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \int_0^{\arcsin(\cos\theta)} \sin \phi \ d\phi \ d\theta \approx 1.1416$

**In cylindrical coordinates,**

$x = \rho \cos\theta, y = \rho \sin\theta, z$

Sphere is given by $r^2 + z^2 = 1$. Cylinder is given by $r = \cos\theta, -\frac{\pi}{2} \leq \theta \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$.

For the given sphere, $|r'_{\rho} \times r'_{\theta}| = \frac{\rho}{\sqrt{1-\rho^2}}$

So the surface area is

$\displaystyle \int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \int_0^{\cos\theta} \frac{\rho}{\sqrt{1-\rho^2}} \ d\rho \ d\theta \approx 1.1416$

Comment: I don't understand the cylindrical coordinates solution.
When using cylindrical coordinates, we want to utilize symmetry around a line right? in $\mathbb{R}^3$ at least.
Which symmetry are you using here?
If you could further explain this parameterization and how you got to it, it would be of great help.

Comment: Sure, the parametrization of the sphere is $(\rho \cos \theta, \rho \sin \theta, \sqrt{1 - \rho^2})$. Then we take derivative wrt $\rho$ and wrt $\theta$ and find $|r'_{\theta} \times r'_{\rho}|$ which comes to $\frac{\rho}{\sqrt{1-\rho^2}}$.

Comment: If you want further details on that, I can update in the answer.

Comment: I simply don't understand where is the cylindrical symmetry here

Comment: We are not using any symmetry. What we are essentially doing is taking projection of spherical surface in XY plane as you see from top. Its boundary is defined by the cylinder. You can see that in the limits of integral I have used. If dS is the surface area and dA is the area of the projection in XY plane, you need to multiply area of the projection in XY plane by $|r'_{\theta} \times r'_{\rho}|$ to get dS.